# Libreoffice dialogue too long

Tags: printing, libreoffice

I want to print a document in libreoffice, the dialogue was too long so I can't press the ok at the bottom, so I found a walkthrough: I can just strike `enter`, which is not too bad.
But today, I want to print something double sided.My printer is old and outdated, so to do this I would print the odd number pages and `reverse print it` and then manually put the papers back inside to the tray and print the even pages.
But the problem now is that when I opened the advanced menu, the printing config page just aligns to the center.
Here's what I meant.
[image: The page is in the middle] [image: The page is too long] [image: The settings is hidden]
PS： When I run `env LANG=en_US.UTF-8 libreoffice --writer`, input sth and `ctrl+p`, everything is fine.
I remember doing an `apt upgrade` recently. So maybe that's tha cause?

Comment: There is indeed an issue where your page preview in the left column leaves a lot of blank space - it is supposed to start at the top of the left column. What version of LibreOffice is this, and how was it installed (apt version or snap version, or external PPA)? Does the issue persist after you change your locale to American US and reboot?

Comment: 版本: 6.4.7.2
Build ID: 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
CPU 线程: 4; 操作系统: Linux 5.11; 界面渲染: 默认; VCL: gtk3; 
区域语言: zh-CN (zh_CN.UTF-8); UI 语言: zh-CN
Calc: threaded

Comment: I installed Ubuntu 20.04 when it was released and chose full install mode. And I remember updating via sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade.

Comment: So yes, it is the standard LO version, which is most guaranteed to work. Would be good now to test whether this is a regionalisation issue: you can start Libreoffice only in English with the command `env LANG=en_US.UTF-8 libreoffice --writer`. If the issue persists, test whether it only occurs in your account or not -  create a new account and see whether the issue persists. If yes, change the new account to English to see if the issue persists. Add any findings that allow to isolate the cause to your question itself: use "edit".

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @vanadium.
Here's what I've done and the problem disappeared.

```
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt remove libreoffice-l10n-zh-cn
sudo apt install libreoffice-l10n-zh-cn
```

Then powered off, grabbed a sandwich, turned on the computer, the problem was resolved.
In short, you remove the l10n package, then reinstall it, then reboot.